# Error "No preset version installed for command curl", but it's installed

Tags: curl, asdf

I tried to use asdf today and something broke.

When I try to **install some version of python** I get this:

```
noki-artix:[noki]:~$ asdf install python 3.8.10
python-build 3.8.10 /home/noki/.asdf/installs/python/3.8.10
Downloading Python-3.8.10.tar.gz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.10/Python-3.8.10.tgz
error: failed to download Python-3.8.10.tar.gz

BUILD FAILED (Artix rolling using python-build 2.2.4-1-10-g0d949796)

Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20220310175911.6108.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/python-build.20220310175911.6108 ~
No preset version installed for command curl
Please install a version by running one of the following:

asdf install python 3.10.2

or add one of the following versions in your config file at 
python anaconda3-5.3.1
```

**The which for curl is:**

```
noki-artix:[noki]:~$ which curl
/home/noki/.asdf/shims/curl
```

1. I do have curl-7.82.0-1 installed (and re-installed), but it's not working I get the error above
2. asdf reshim was run
3. I did Google for a couple of hours now, but I don't know how to define if it's a curl problem or an asdf problem, or even something else...
4. Artix Runit with LTS kernel

Thank you all;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uninstall anaconda and my problem went away.

```
asdf uninstall python anaconda3-5.3.1
```

I arrived at that because of the `cat /home/noki/.asdf/shims/curl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# asdf-plugin: python anaconda3-5.3.1
exec /home/noki/.asdf/bin/asdf exec "curl" "$@"
```

after uninstalling anaconda the shims for curl was removed

```
cat: /home/noki/.asdf/shims/curl: No such file or directory
```

And all works well.